# Aggregate values and also keep records

Tags: mysql

I'm new here and I hope I'll meet the requirements to be understandable.

I have a Table

| Product ID | Movement type | From Warehouse | To Warehouse | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | OUT | TT | XX | 3 |
| A | IN | TT | TT | 3 |
| A | IN | BB | BB | 3 |
| A | OUT | ZZ | BB | 3 |
| A | OUT | ZZ | CC | 21 |
| A | IN | ZZ | ZZ | 25 |

So it means That I Have in total

31 "IN" and "27" OUT (Stock in TRANSIT) So 4 Item Sent but not received yet

I would like to Retrieve which Quantity of item A is in Transit And To Which Warehouse it should Arrive.

So finally Get a table like this

| Product ID | Movement type | From Warehouse | To Warehouse | Quantity | TOTAL DIFF IN AND OUT | Total i GET (WRONG) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | IN | XX | XX | 3 | 4 | 300000000000 |
| A | OUT | XX | TT | 3 | 4 | 300000000000 |
| A | OUT | ZZ | BB | 3 | 4 | 300000000000 |
| A | OUT | ZZ | CC | 21 | 4 | 300000000000 |
| A | IN | ZZ | ZZ | 25 | 4 | 300000000000 |
| A | IN | TT | TT | 3 | 4 | 300000000000 |

Where i could Filter this "TOTAL DIFF IN AND OUT"

Which is above 0

To reduce Extract Time from the database (12 years of data)

Here's My query with a specific Item.

But I would like to Have the Total Value per Item Not the total quantity.

The SQL Come from CEGID ERP, I don't know exactly which SQL it runs

```
SELECT 
GL_ARTICLE AS CLEF_UNIQUE_ARTICLE, 
GL_NATUREPIECEG AS NATURE_DE_MOUVEMENT,  
GPP_LIBELLE AS LIBELLE_NATURE_DE_MOUVEMENT,  
GL_REFARTBARRE AS CODE_BARRES_ARTICLE,

GL_DEPOT AS DEPOT,
GP_DEPOTDEST AS DEPOT_DESTINATION,


    sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TEM" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) AS EMIS,
    sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TRE" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) AS RECU,
    sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TEM" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) - sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TRE" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) as ECART_EMIS_RECU,

(select sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TEM" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) as EMIS
from LIGNE L1
Where L1.GL_ARTICLE Like "%!TURQUOISE%" AND L1.GL_NATUREPIECEG IN ("TEM"))-


(select sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TRE" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) as EMIS1
from LIGNE L2
Where L2.GL_ARTICLE Like "%!TURQUOISE%" AND L2.GL_NATUREPIECEG IN ("TRE")) AS DIFF_TOTAL



FROM PIECE


LEFT JOIN LIGNE ON GP_NUMERO = GL_NUMERO AND GP_NATUREPIECEG = GL_NATUREPIECEG AND GL_DATEPIECE = GP_DATEPIECE 

LEFT JOIN PARPIECE ON GL_NATUREPIECEG = GPP_NATUREPIECEG


WHERE GL_ARTICLE Like "%!TURQUOISE%"  AND GL_NATUREPIECEG IN ("TEM","TRE") AND (select sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TEM" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) as EMIS
from LIGNE L1
Where L1.GL_ARTICLE Like "%!TURQUOISE%" AND L1.GL_NATUREPIECEG IN ("TEM"))-


(select sum(case when GL_NATUREPIECEG = "TRE" then GL_QTESTOCK else 0 end) as EMIS1
from LIGNE L2
Where L2.GL_ARTICLE Like "%!TURQUOISE%" AND L2.GL_NATUREPIECEG IN ("TRE")) > 0

GROUP BY
GL_ARTICLE, 
GL_NATUREPIECEG,  
GPP_LIBELLE,  
      
GL_REFARTBARRE,

GL_DEPOT,
GP_DEPOTDEST
ORDER BY GL_ARTICLE asc
```

Actually, if I remove the specific item "!TURQUOISE"  The column "TOTAL DIFF IN AND OUT"

Contains All quantities for all items :(

Anyone could help,

so many searches I'm totally tired!

Many thanks

Comment: Can you explain how/why the quantity values changed from your source table to your expected results?  maybe we need to write to queries to union the results    for example why is the 3rd line NULL and why did 21 become 24 and 25 remain the same?

Comment: Hi, lord I'm sorry,  the 21 should have remained 21, error when typing.

Comment: As per example. If I remove the item "!turquoise" I get a sum like 3000000000000 items which is the sum of each in (or out) movement for every items in the database. I just would like to keep the group of last column by product ID (gl_article) in my case

Answer (score 0):

Just an example looking at last column added: I don't fully understand the question yet.

Just looking at your tables and expected results: This could be completed using a case statement and window function.  case to determine if "out" so multiply quantity by -1.  and window function to aggregate by product.  I didn't review your SQL, I looked at the "table" in your example and went from there...

The window function sums all the quantity *(-1 or 1 based on out or in) for each product.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5a90824b5658ab5ee435e4889f8dad5

```
WITH SRC as (
SELECT 'A' Product_ID,  'OUT' Movement_type,    'TT' From_Warehouse,    'XX' To_Warehouse,  3 Quantity UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'IN',   'TT',   'TT',   3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'IN',   'BB',   'BB',   3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'OUT',  'ZZ',   'BB',   3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'OUT',  'ZZ',   'CC',   21 UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'IN',   'ZZ',   'ZZ',   25)

SELECT A.*, Sum(case Movement_type when 'OUT' then -1 else 1 end *Quantity)
over (Partition by product_ID) Total_Diff_by_Product 
FROM SRC A
```

Givng you

```
+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------------------+
| Product_ID | Movement_type | From_Warehouse | To_Warehouse | Quantity | Total_Diff_by_Product |
+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------------------+
| A          | OUT           | TT             | XX           |        3 |                     4 |
| A          | IN            | TT             | TT           |        3 |                     4 |
| A          | IN            | BB             | BB           |        3 |                     4 |
| A          | OUT           | ZZ             | BB           |        3 |                     4 |
| A          | OUT           | ZZ             | CC           |       21 |                     4 |
| A          | IN            | ZZ             | ZZ           |       25 |                     4 |
+------------+---------------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: may need to partition by the from and to warehouses as well to adjust quantity values.  I'm not sure how the quantities change based on sample data...

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your answer, I'll give a try tomorrow morning. In fact I have one more difficulty. One on my warehouse is the starting point of each goods. Going through the company. Then from this warehouse everything is dispatched to other warehouses. I'm already taking stock levels into account somewhere else in the process. So actually I just need to know quantity in transit

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry but I can't Apply your strategy. In fact i can obtain the result i want using the code i posted here above.  The only problem is that when I change The condition on GL_ARTICLE (L1.GL_ARTICLE and also L2.GL_ARTICLE) to get the total result on each product , i get the result over each product of the database. Which is not the desired output